# Which style is better to declare a type in Ocaml?

Tags: list, types, dictionary, ocaml

I often need to declare a type which contains a map or a list, for instance:

```
type my_type_1 = my_type_0 IntMap.t
type my_type_2 = my_type_0 List
```

Also I have seen another style of declaration which encapsulates map or list in a record, for instance:

```
type my_type_1 =
  | Bot_1
  | Nb_1 of my_type_0 IntMap.t
type my_type_2 =
  | Bot_2
  | Nb_2 of my_type_0 List
```

My question is, whether there are some cases where the second style is necessary and better than the first style?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two types you give are not equivalent, because of the `Bot` constructor added in the second case. This means that the two `my_type_1` do not have the same semantics. Incidentally, the construction `Bot | Foo of 'a` is already provided by the standard type `'a option`, with constructors `Some` and `None`, so the type `my_type_1` of your second sample is equivalent to a `my_type_1 option` in the first one.

Whether to use an `option` type or your own constructors names is up to you. In general, I would advise to you an option type if the semantics of your type coincides with the `option` idea of failure, being absent, or being undefined. Given your name `Bot`, I assume this is probably what you're doing, but defining your own constructor names is also ok and can be clearer in some circumstances. The matter has been discussed in depth in [this blog post from ezyang](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/04/type-kata-local-data-type/).

Now, assuming your two types definition *were* equivalent (that is, in absence of the `Bot`) constructor, what's the purpose of adding an algebraic datatype layer, a new constructor, instead of using a simple type alias ? Well, it has the effect of making your type *distinct* from the representation type. For example, if you define `type 'a stack = Stack of 'a list`, `'a stack` and `'a list` cannot be confused for each other, and the compiler will raise an error if you do. So that can be used to enforce a (light) type separation, with the constructor acting as a type annotation:

```
let empty = Stack []
let length (Stack li) = List.length li
```

I'd say it's mostly a matter of taste, but I would recommend using an algebraic datatype instead of an alias when you want to be sure that there can be no mistake with the original type. The downside is that you have to wrap the operations of the original datatype, as I did in my `length` function above.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not different *styles*, but different *types*: the first type declarations are an abbreviation for a specialized instance (for `mytype_0`) of the polymorphic `List`, or `IntMap`.

The second set of definitions present a "*constructed*" type, for which `Bot_1` (and `Bot_2`) provide values. Those "alternatives" can be used, for example, to create functions of type `T -> my_type_1` which return `Bot_1` in a special case where the computation doesn't allow to return a list, in a similar way of what an [option type](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/u3-ocaml/ocaml-core.html#Exo-13) permits. This is impossible with the first set of definitions (who must always provide the required list payload).

Answer (score 0):

The second one isn't a "record" (which is a different thing). It creates an algebraic data type. I'm not sure how to explain it but if you've used Haskell or Standard ML you'll know. It's basically a tagged union. A `my_type_1` is *either* a `Bot_1` (which carries no data) or a `Nb_1` (which carries a `my_type_0 IntMap.t` as data).

The first one is simply a type synonym (like a typedef in C).